# SAS PROC SQL NOT CONTAINS multiple values in one statement

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

In PROC SQL, I need to select all rows where a column called "NAME" does not contain multiple values "abc", "cde" and "fbv" regardless of what comes before or after these values. So I did it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE
  NAME NOT CONTAINS "abc" 
  AND
  NAME NOT CONTAINS "cde"
  AND
  NAME NOT CONTAINS "fbv";
```

which works just fine, but I imagine it would be a headache if we had a hundred of conditions. So my question is - can we accomplish this in a single statement in PROC SQL? 
I tried using this:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE 
  NOT CONTAINS(NAME, '"abc" AND "cde" AND "fbv"');
```

but this doesn't work in PROC SQL, I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: Function CONTAINS could not be located.

I don't want to use LIKE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions, I suppose.

```
data a;
input name $;
datalines;
xyabcde
xyzxyz
xycdeyz
xyzxyzxyz
fbvxyz
;;;;
run;

proc sql;

SELECT * FROM A WHERE
  NAME NOT CONTAINS "abc" 
  AND
  NAME NOT CONTAINS "cde"
  AND
  NAME NOT CONTAINS "fbv";


SELECT * FROM A WHERE
  NOT (PRXMATCH('~ABC|CDE|FBV~i',NAME));
quit;
```

You can't use CONTAINS that way, though.

Comment: Worked great, thanks! ~ means wildcard I am assuming?

Comment: `~` is just a delimiter, you have to start and end a regex with any delimiter that's not used in the regex.  Regular expressions match 'anywhere' unless you anchor them to start or end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE 
  NAME NOT IN ('abc','cde','fbv');
```

Comment: But I need it to exclude any record(s) containing e.g. 'abc' regardless of how many characters are before or after 'abc'.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of items is above reasonable number to build inside code, you can create a table (work.words below) to store the words and iterate over it to check occurrences:

```
data work.values;
input name $;
datalines;
xyabcde
xyzxyz
xycdeyz
xyzxyzxyz
fbvxyz
;
run;

data work.words;
length word $50;
input word $;
datalines;
abc
cde
fbv
;
run;


data output;
set values;

/* build a has of words */
length word $50;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
   /* this runs once only */
   call missing(word);
   declare hash words (dataset: 'work.words');
   words.defineKey('word');
   words.defineData('word');
   words.defineDone();
end;

/* iterate hash of words */
declare hiter iter('words'); 
rc = iter.first();
found = 0;
do while (rc=0); 
   if index(name, trim(word)) gt 0 then do; /* check if word present using INDEX function */
      found= 1;
      rc = 1;
   end;
   else rc = iter.next();
end;
if found = 0 then output; /* output only if no word found in name */
drop word rc found;
run;
```